# How to use jQuery to filter divs based on certain classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I am trying to create a filter system for a list of divs that contain a series of classes based on their content.  So if I pick an option in 1 select, then the visible options will change based on that class name.  Then I have 2 more selects with different values that I am trying to use to make the "filter" even more specific.  I can figure out how to do these filters separately, but I can't figure out how to combine the function into 1 multi-class check.  I have tried to use hasClass(), filter(), and a couple other options, but I think there is something that I am missing here.  It doesn't want to work the way that I am trying to make it.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/theVurv/xpvt214o/435655/) that I am working on to try and figure this out for a much larger project.

First, I have a set of selects:

```
<select name="select-1" id="select-1">
   <option value="allColors">All</option>
   <option value="Red">Red</option>
   <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<select name="select-2" id="select-2">
   <option value="allShapes">All</option>
   <option value="Square">Square</option>
   <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
</select>
<select name="select-3" id="select-3">
   <option value="allStyles">All</option>
   <option value="Solid">Solid</option>
   <option value="Outline">Outline</option>
</select>
```

Then I have a set of divs with various classes to distinguish them:

```
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Square Solid">
This is a solid, red square.
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Square Outline">
This is a red, square outline.
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Circle Solid">
This is a solid, red circle.
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Circle Outline">
This is a red, circle outline.
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Square Solid">
This is a solid, blue square.
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Square Outline">
This is a blue, square outline.
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Circle Solid">
This is a solid, blue circle.
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Circle Outline">
This is a blue, circle outline.
</div>
```

I wrote some jQuery that will let me run a filter on all the divs for each select separately, but I want to be able to combine the 3 selects into 1 function, that checks all the divs for the selected classes, and shows them if they are all present, or hides them if they don't.

The latest 2 attempts I tried are as follows:
(the first attempt is commented out, and the latest is the one still active.  Neither worked...)

```
jQuery('#selectContainer select').on('change', function() {
var color = '.' + jQuery('#select-1').val();
var shape = '.' + jQuery('#select-2').val();
var style = '.' + jQuery('#select-3').val();
var selectedClasses = (color + ' ' + shape + ' ' + style);

  jQuery('div.object').hide();

/*   if(jQuery('div.object').hasClass(selectedClasses)) {
    jQuery('div.object' + selectedClasses).show();
  } */

  if(jQuery('div.object').hasClass(color) && jQuery('div.object').hasClass(shape) && jQuery('div.object').hasClass(style)) {
    jQuery('div.object' + ' ' + selectedClasses).show();
  }

  console.log(selectedClasses);
});
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong, or where I should even begin would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out with the help of a friend.  The correct jQuery should be:

```
jQuery('#selectContainer select').on('change', function() {
var color = jQuery('#select-1').val();
var shape = jQuery('#select-2').val();
var style = jQuery('#select-3').val();

  jQuery('div.object').hide();

  jQuery('div.object').each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass(color) && jQuery(this).hasClass(shape) && jQuery(this).hasClass(style)) {
    jQuery(this).show();
    }
  });

});
```

and that gets the result I was looking for.  [Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/theVurv/xpvt214o/436020/).  Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Please take a look at the solution I posted prior to yours at your convenience.  It accomplishes the same thing without needing to use .each() or .hasClass().

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for you:

```
// you can target all of the select fields by just using
// jQuery(#selectContainer select) so that you don't have to write
// a separate onChange function for each individual select field
jQuery('#selectContainer select').on('change', function() {

    // define each of the select fields (color, shape, style)
    var color = '.' + jQuery('#select-1').val();
    var shape = '.' + jQuery('#select-2').val();
    var style = '.' + jQuery('#select-3').val();

    // To check whether an element has multiple classes, you 
    // shouldn't have white space between the class names.
    // e.g. classes will output like this: .class1.class2.class3
    var selectedClasses = (color + shape + style);

    // Hide all divs (will only stay hidden for a few milliseconds)
    jQuery('div.object').hide();

    // Show only the elements that have all three classes
    jQuery(selectedClasses).show();  

});
```

And here is the corresponding Pen: https://codepen.io/VisualHarmony/pen/GBqQYp