# How to keep the last preferences in the Jquery select / option filter system?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filter

I've found a very useful [Jquery example to filter divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392299/how-to-use-jquery-to-filter-divs-based-on-certain-classes) based on changing select options.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vgdwyqxb/

**My problem is:**
I use this code for filtering projects and every single project has a URL that goes to another page. When a user clicks on a project, he/she goes to project detail page. On those pages, there is a "Go Back" button. When they go back, all filtering selections are lost. I want to hold the filter selections.

I added a *goBack()* method in other page to go back to filter page. When I click on *goback*, filter page remembers which option was selected but all divs appear (not filtering divs). As far as i know "changing option" must be done in order to filter divs, so when i go back to filter page, even my last selected option is selected, it doesn't filter anymore.

My question is: What should i do to make filter page remember when users go back from project detail page?

Thanks in advance.

```js
jQuery('#selectContainer select').on('change', function() {
var color = jQuery('#select-1').val();
var shape = jQuery('#select-2').val();
var style = jQuery('#select-3').val();


  jQuery('div.object').hide();
  
  jQuery('div.object').each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass(color) && jQuery(this).hasClass(shape) && jQuery(this).hasClass(style)) {
    jQuery(this).show();
    }
  });
  
});


//$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#btnAuckland').click(function(){ 

    $('#select-1').val('Red').trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selectContainer">
  <select name="select-1" id="select-1">
        <option value="allColors">All</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select-2" id="select-2">
        <option value="allShapes">All</option>
        <option value="Square">Square</option>
        <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select-3" id="select-3">
        <option value="allStyles" selected>All</option>
        <option value="Solid">Solid</option>
        <option value="Outline">Outline</option>
    </select>
</div>
    <hr />
    <div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Square Solid">
        <p><a href="nextpage.html"> This is a solid, red square. </a> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Square Outline">
        <p>This is a red, square outline.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Circle Solid">
        <p>This is a solid, red circle.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Circle Outline">
        <p>This is a red, circle outline.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Square Solid">
        <p>This is a solid, blue square.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Square Outline">
        <p>This is a blue, square outline.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Circle Solid">
        <p>This is a solid, blue circle.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Circle Outline">
        <p>This is a blue, circle outline.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: i think you need to use `localStorage` for trigger the filters with "old" data

Comment: If it did remember the selected options, then all you should need to do is run your filter logic on page load as well, no?

Comment: Try : `jQuery('#selectContainer select').trigger("change")` on page load.

Comment: Like @SimoneRossaini answer `localStorage` this is exactly what you need [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can use [`localStorage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save a JSON-encoded string which contains the last selections made from the three filter `select` elements.

When the page is loaded you can then retrieve that JSON, apply the selected values back to the `select` and filter the content once more.
Here's what the code to do this could look like:

```js
// Save the selected values to JSON in localStorage
let saveObjectFilterSettings = () => {
  let filters = $('#selectContainer select').map((i, el) => ({
    id: el.id,
    val: el.value
  })).get();
  localStorage.setItem('filter', JSON.stringify(filters));
}

// Retrieve the filter JSON from localStorage and apply it to the DOM
let retrieveObjectFilterSettings = () => {
  let filters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('filter') || '[]');
  filters.forEach(obj => $(`#${obj.id}`).val(obj.val));
}

// Apply the selected filters to the DOM
let filterObjects = () => {
  var color = $('#select-1').val();
  var shape = $('#select-2').val();
  var style = $('#select-3').val();

  $('div.object').each(function() {
    let $el = $(this);
    $el.toggle($el.hasClass(color) && $el.hasClass(shape) && $el.hasClass(style))
  });
}

jQuery($ => {
  retrieveObjectFilterSettings();
  filterObjects();

  $('#selectContainer select').on('change', function() {
    saveObjectFilterSettings();
    filterObjects();
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selectContainer">
  <select name="select-1" id="select-1">
    <option value="allColors">All</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select-2" id="select-2">
    <option value="allShapes">All</option>
    <option value="Square">Square</option>
    <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select-3" id="select-3">
    <option value="allStyles" selected>All</option>
    <option value="Solid">Solid</option>
    <option value="Outline">Outline</option>
  </select>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Square Solid">
  <p><a href="nextpage.html"> This is a solid, red square. </a> </p>
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Square Outline">
  <p>This is a red, square outline.</p>
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Circle Solid">
  <p>This is a solid, red circle.</p>
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Red Circle Outline">
  <p>This is a red, circle outline.</p>
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Square Solid">
  <p>This is a solid, blue square.</p>
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Square Outline">
  <p>This is a blue, square outline.</p>
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Circle Solid">
  <p>This is a solid, blue circle.</p>
</div>
<div class="object allColors allShapes allStyles Blue Circle Outline">
  <p>This is a blue, circle outline.</p>
</div>
```

Here's a working example in a [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/t2Lovfz3/) - I had to use a fiddle for this as SO snippets are sandboxed and don't allow access to localStorage.

Comment: Dear Rory, 

I'm very thankful for your contribution.